Cannot modify startDate and endDate in Event
I am facing issues with startDate and endDate fields of an Event.
By using Inspector (chrome extension), I can edit them. I am the one assigned to the Event. But from the layout, this is the behaviour:
VIEW MODE:

EDIT MODE:

As you can see both fields disappear from the layout in edit mode. It uses a standard layout.
If you have any doubt of the context please, let me know.
Thanks

Are you using standard pagelayout or dynamic form? what happens when you click the edit icon besides the start?

Standard layout, I have even no option to make it dynamic.

Any chance you are using a custom Global Action for Event (Setup > Global Action) where the layout has start/end dates defined as read only?

I add here what happens, looks frontend, because it's randomly dissapearing https://youtu.be/FPjTcM1qSdo but it only happens to me in this org, not in other projects
